# Selecting PNP transistor replacement

Tags: transistors, pcb, component-selection, pnp

In my circuit I have a discontinued transistor listed here:

[image]

If I can not select a transistor rated 350 mA, would a change to the collector current pose any issues that may need compensating in my circuit? I am assuming that is what the 350 mA represents in the BOM, as Fairchild does not exist anymore.

The same part name from [onsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/pzt3906-d.pdf) is listed as Transistor PNP 40 V, 200 mA collector current.

The 5 V/5 A circuit:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MMBT3906 is one of those parts you can get from a bunch of manufacturers, and which is probably never going to be totally unavailable. [Onsemi](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/onsemi/SMMBT3906LT1G/5213405) still makes them under a slightly different part number, [Diodes](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/MMBT3906-7-F/822858) makes them, [Comchip](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/comchip-technology/MMBT3906-HF/9477881) makes them, [Nexperia](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/MMBT3906-215/1944321) makes them, and that's only the first few I could find.

Comment: Right, so what is listed in the BOM then, why is it listed as 350 mA? I am a stickler for detail and am a bit out of my league in electrical design. Is that simply a typo or caused by using the incorrect component? I assume all MMBT3906 components would have the same specs...

Comment: @WesEllgass It's probably a mistake. I suppose you could probably push 350 mA through a 3906 if you had a way to cool it better, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Every variety of xx3906 transistor I've seen is rated at 200 mA, from the leaded TO-92 2N3906 to the surface mount MMBT3906 and PZT3906.

The FSCT on the part number is I think from DigiKey, denoting a cut-tape packaged version, and as you can see [here](https://www.digikey.lt/en/products/detail/onsemi/MMBT3906/458869) it is listed as 200 mA.

I would say that the 350 mA rating was most likely a mistake and you should be able to replace it with an MMBT3906 from another manufacturer.

If you're still worried about it you might find a similar transistor that has a higher collector current rating, the 3906 family are general purpose transistors, so  it's probably not critical, find one with similar power dissipation, \$V_{CE}\$ and \$H_{FE}\$ ratings but higher \$I_C\$ and you should be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can sub a beefier transistor such as [MMBT4403](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbt4403-d.pdf), which is a 60V 600mA part and costs only slightly more than an inferior MMBT3906.